# How to draw time series plot for data in date format in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have data where there are dates of visits of children.

```
date
16.08.13
16.08.13
16.08.13
17.08.13
27.08.13
03.09.13
04.09.13
05.09.13
07.09.13
07.09.13
```

I want to draw a time series plot in R that shows the dates and corresponding number of visits. For example, above there are 3 children on 16.08.2013.

In addition, my data cover 3 years. So, I would like to see the seasonal change over 3 years.

Comment: I am in new to time series in R. So, I do not know which function to use and amhoping to get some advice here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let us create a longer data set called `r`.  Use `table` to compute the frequencies, convert to a zoo time series and plot.  Then compute the mean of each year/month and create a `monthplot`.  Finally plot the means over all months vs month.

```
# test data
set.seed(123)
r <- as.Date("2000-01-01") + cumsum(rpois(1000, 1))

library(zoo)

opar <- par(mfrow = c(2,2)) # create a 2x2 grid of plots - optional

# plot freq vs. time
tab <- table(r)
z <- zoo(c(tab), as.Date(names(tab)))
plot(z) # this will be the upper left plot

# plot each month separately
zm <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, mean)
monthplot(zm) # upper right plot

# plot month means
# zc <- aggregate(zm, cycle(zm), mean) # alternative but not equivalent
zc <- aggregate(z, cycle(as.yearmon(time(z))), mean)
plot(zc) # lower plot

par(opar) # reset grid
```

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** The sum of z for each year/month is zym and the average of those for all the January months, all the February months, ...., all December months is:

```
zym <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon(time(z)), sum)
aggregate(zym, cycle(as.yearmon(time(zym))), mean)
```

Comment: Does the third plot show the average number of visitors in each month? If so, how are they calculated? The total number of cases in each month / 30?

Comment: To understand how they are calculated, I counted the number of cases in January in each year. In total, there are 87 cases over the three years in your data. However, I could not get where about 1.65 in the plot comes from?

Comment: Try this: `mean(z[cycle(as.yearmon(time(z))) == 1])`  whicih computes a logical vector which is TRUE for Jan and FALSE otherwise, subsets z by that vector and takes the mean of those z values.

Comment: Have added a note at the end giving the average number each Jan, each Feb, ..., each Dec.

Answer (score 1):

With ggplot and scale packages you can try something like this (which is a piece of my code that actually works):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

g_sm_ddply <- ggplot(final_data, aes(x = as.Date(dates), y = scon_me, fill = tipo))
g_sm_ddply + geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
    labs(title = "SCONTRINO MEDIO ACQ_ISS_KPMG NUOVA CLUSTERIZZAZIONE", x = "data", y = "scontrino medio")+
    scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("month"), labels = date_format("%Y/%m"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are already familiar with basic data manipulation in R.

One way to do what you want, is to tabulate the date vector and create a proper times series object or a `data.frame`

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(date)) ### tabulate
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d.%m.%y") ### turn your date to Date class
df
##         date Freq
## 1 2013-09-03    1
## 2 2013-09-04    1
## 3 2013-09-05    1
## 4 2013-09-07    2
## 5 2013-08-16    3
## 6 2013-08-17    1
## 7 2013-08-27    1

plot(Freq ~ date, data = df, pch = 19) ### plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So far we are still missing the seasonal trend analysis the OP asked for. I think it is the more difficult part of the question.

If your data covers only 3 years, you can maybe observe the seasonal changes by simple looking at the monthly average daily visits.

Depending on your needs you can go with a simple monthly plot or you might have to prepare further your data to compute the exact trend in seasonality.

Below a suggestion on how to compute and plot the Monthly average number visits per day (with at least one visit per day)

```
library(ggplot2)
df<-read.table(text="
16.08.13
16.08.13
16.08.13
17.08.13
27.08.13
03.09.13
04.10.13
05.09.13
07.09.13
07.01.14
03.02.14
04.03.14
04.03.14
04.03.14
15.05.14
15.05.14
15.09.14
20.10.14
20.09.14 ", col.names="date")
df <- as.data.frame(table(df)) #get the frequency count (daily)
df$date <- as.Date(df$df, "%d.%m.%y") # turn your date variable to Date class
df$year<-sapply(df$df,function(x) strptime(x,"%d.%m.%Y")$year+1900) #extract month of the visit
df$month<-sapply(df$df,function(x) strptime(x,"%d.%m.%Y")$mon+1) #extract year of the visit

#plot daily frequency
ggplot(aes(x=date, y=Freq), data = df) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')+
  ggtitle("Daily visits")

#compute monthly average visit per day (for days with at least one visit)
library(dplyr)
df2<-df[,c("year","month","Freq")]%>% 
  group_by(year,month) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE))) 

#recreate a date for the graph
df2$date<-as.Date(paste(rep("01",length(df2)),df2$month,df2$year),"%d %m %y") 

ggplot(aes(x=date, y=Freq), data = df2) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')+
  ggtitle("Average daily visits per month")
```